# method signatures in scala : Map(String, Int)

Tags: scala

I want to declare a method explicitly with a return type as in :

```
def method() : Int = {}
```

But I want to return a `Map((String,Int))` instead. So far I couldnT make it work.

Is this an invalid method signature in scala? if so why?

```
def parseEmptySpaceLine0 (array: Array[String]): Map(String, Int) = { 

 //stuff
 Map("", 1)
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic type parameter should be enclosed in `[]`, not in `()`. Much like the `Array[String]` in your signature.

So it's `Map[String, Int]` you're looking for.